# jQuery- Making variable available inside function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a predefined variable inside a number of functions (its an API key that I use in several functions on the page):

```
var key = '12345';

function get_dom(query) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.example.com?key='+key+'&q='+query,
        success: function (data) {
          // do stuff...
        }
    });
}
```

How do I get `key` available inside the function? I keep getting `undefined`

Comment: by passing it as param =x

Comment: From your code, it should be working already ..

Comment: Do you have any issue accessing it?

Comment: The example posted works perfectly fine, there's no possible way it wouldn't work as written, as the variable is within scope

Comment: @Satpal yes, the variable is not available inside the function. It returns as nothing.

Comment: It if it's not producing an "undefined variable" error, you've changed it somewhere without keeping proper track of it.

Comment: Yes, if I try to do an alert I get `undefined`

Comment: You get an error in the console, or you get the actual value `undefined`, there's a difference ?

Comment: How are you calling `get_dom()`?  Where is `key` set?  They are probably not in the same scope.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It is called on document ready on an external PHP page.

Comment: @JROB: And where is `key` set?  This could be a scope issue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Immediately above the function as shown above.

Comment: Wait, there actually is a way to get undefined, you're calling the function before the variable is defined, only possible explanation, see this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8E2LA/1/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you state that the get_dom() function is called on document ready. Often, when scoping issues then arise it is because that you forget that the event callbacks for things like document ready are executed in the global scope, and the variable you are trying to access is not in the global scope. Is it defined in some kind of inner scope, say, a wrapper function? People often do that to make the script unobtrusive. 
To mitigate this, you can wrap the callback in a proxy function that makes sure the scope is what you want it to be. I've personally messed this up countless times, it's so easy to do wrong.